# how to use .htaccess with PHPDesktop?

Tags: phpdesktop

I'm trying to get my `.htaccess` file to work with **PHPDesktop**, but `.htaccess` doesn't seem to work. I saw that it's possible to hide specific files in the `settings.json` file, but it seems pretty limited. Is there a way to use my `.htaccess` file instead of using the `settings.json` file? Here's what I use for my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^public/(.+) public/$1 [END] # allow direct access on public folder
RewriteRule ^ index.php [END]            # anything else will be directed to index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use .htaccess with PHP Desktop. PHP Desktop embeds a Mongoose web server which doesn't support such configuration file.

The rewrite rules from your .htaccess can be handled by setting `web_server > 404_handler` in settings.json file to `/index.php`.

Comment: Seems like a simple solution, but what about files that exist? The reason I have this .htaccess is to make use of a router, so everything (with the exception of the public folder, which has css, javascript and images) goes through index.php. Your solution would only take care of non-existent files.

Comment: @noClue PHP Desktop provides only basic support for rewrite rules to handle 404 requests. You have control over files and requests, so you should be able to resolve any issues that you have.

Comment: So I solved my issue by defining a constant variable in index.php, which is the only php file you should be allowed to access directly: `define("accessible", TRUE);`. Then, in any of the php files I don't want to be accessed directly, I just add this: `if(!defined("accessible")) { header("Location: ../"); die(); }`. Works perfectly, along with the `web_server > 404_handler` setting in the settings.json file. Thanks!